# Can't create an instance of a class (no default constructor)

Tags: c++, class

> **Edit:**

**I've found the solution by myself. I'm sorry for this question, that wasn't fully understanble for You.**

Okey, I have so much code in my program. I'm writing a tree with using a list,that I'm going to write. I can't use STL library.

**30_Contaner.h:**

```
#pragma once
#include "Container_5_30.h"
#include "Tree.h"
#include "List.h"


using std::cout;
using std::cin;


class Tree : public AbstractTree
{//Cathy
protected:

    struct ListStruct{
        void* key;
        size_t size;
        ListStruct* next;
    };

    //Iterator *globalIterator;

    class List : public AbstractList{
    public:

        /*some code*/

        List(MemoryManager& mem) :AbstractList(mem){//constructor

        }

        virtual ~List(){

        }

        //some functions
    };

    struct TreeStruct{
        TreeStruct *parent;
        //OneLinkedList* Children = new OneLinkedList;
        List *Children;//error
        void *elem;
        size_t size;
        int childIndex;
    };


    int numberOfElements;
    bool globalBoolForRecursion;
    //TreeStruct *TreeStructInstance = new TreeStruct;
    List *ListInstance = new List;//error


public:

    Tree(MemoryManager& mem) :AbstractTree(mem) {
        //root = new TreeStruct;//root - корень дерева (элемент структуры Дерева)
        numberOfElements = 0;//кол-во элементов в дереве пока что 0
    }

//some functions

};
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "30_Container.h"
#include "30_Mem.h"
#include "Tree.h"



//********************************

    void main(){


        Mem mem(100);

        Tree tree(mem);

        //some code
    }
```

30_Mem.h

```
#pragma once
#include "MemoryManager.h"

// Простейший менеджер памяти, использует ::new и ::delete

    class Mem : public MemoryManager
    {
    public:
        Mem(size_t sz) :MemoryManager(sz) {}

        void* allocMem(size_t sz) { return new char[sz]; }

        void freeMem(void* ptr) { delete[] ptr; }
    };
```

All methods in AbstractTree,MemoryManager and AbstractList classes are virtual. I should get instance of List class inside Tree class. But, I have a problem: I don't have default constructor for List and, of course, when I write `List *list = new List;` I have an error. My teacher told me that I should use pointer to memory manager of tree, or address, may be. Do you have any idea?
P.S. I need 30_Mem.h in the future. I should be writing my own `new`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of default initialization for ListInstance add initialization of ListInstance to constructor

```
Tree(MemoryManager& mem) :AbstractTree(mem), ListInstance(mem) {
    //root = new TreeStruct;//root - корень дерева (элемент структуры Дерева)
    numberOfElements = 0;//кол-во элементов в дереве пока что 0
}
```

Comment: if I want to do in any functions of Tree class this: `tree->Children = new List; `What to do with `new List`, if there isn't default constructor?

Comment: `List *list = new List(this->_memory); `( `_memory` is from Abstract class in Container.h). Your solution works only if i declares instance before constructor, but that is really neccessary information for me. Спасибо))) Просто мою программу надо видеть, чтобы полностью понять, что именно я хотела узнать